# How to add Karma+Mocha tests after initializing project using vue-cli

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, karma-mocha, karma-webpack, vue-cli

Hi I started a project using Vue-cli webpack the mistake I did was I did not enable tests

How do I add karma+mocha to my webpack vuejs2 development is it possible to reinitialize and include tests ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your package.json add the following :

```
"karma": "^1.7.0",
"karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
"karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
"mocha": "^3.0.2",
"chai": "~4.1.1",
```

in karma.conf.js:

```
const wpConf = require("./webpack.config")
wpConf.devtool = "inline-source-map"

module.exports = config => {
  config.set({
    browsers:      ["PhantomJS"],
    files:         ["./socialhome/**/app/tests/**/*\.tests\.js"],
    frameworks:    ["mocha"],
    plugins:       [
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
        "karma-mocha",
        "karma-sourcemap-loader",
        "karma-webpack"
    ],
    preprocessors: {"./socialhome/**/app/tests/**/*\.tests\.js": ["webpack", "sourcemap"]},
    reporters:     ["dots"],
    singleRun:     true,
    webpack:       wpConf
})
}
```

again in your package.json :

```
"scripts": {
   "dev": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch",
   "test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start"
}
```

in order to use the latest ECMAScript syntax, I passed Karma via webpack before launching test.

I hope this help.

Comment: In Vue cli 3, there is no webpack.config.js file. How should I proceed in that case?

Comment: @silva96. I moved my project to Vue cli 3 and installed jest using a separate jest.config.json file.

Comment: We ended up doing the same, jest is the response to all the problems